# Javascript string.indexOf('') causing webpage to hang

Tags: javascript

This line of code seems to make my webpage become unresponsive and I'm not sure why and it does run the code. This is Javascript. I am using Firebug on firefox to debug.

```
i = response.indexOf(',');
```

Comment: What is the value of `response`?

Comment: What is `response`, and what is the context of this line?

Comment: what is the value of `response`

Comment: This doesn't hang your browser, do you have something like `while(i){}` ? `.indexOf` returns a truthy value (`-1`) when the string isn't found.

Comment: `var response = {indexOf: function(){ for(;;); }}` could cause this to hang the browser.

Comment: response is a String containing one,two,three,four

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using a loop:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    // Smart move here:
    i = 'x'.indexOf('y'); // Not found, so i = -1;
}
```

Setting `i` to -1 causes the loop to continue infinitely. Make sure that neither `i` variable leak to a common scope, by prefixing [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) before `i`, and not using the same variable multiple times within the same scope.

Comment: I have found out why it wasn't the line of code but where the code was positioned. I had it after the readyState and status if statement from within the XMLHttpRequest function. I placed it inside the if statement and all is fine. Does any one know why this is?